# ¿por que me funciona de manera local pero no en el servidor? (retorno en json de consulta a la db)

Tags: php

Buenas tardes tengo un problema el código a continuación el cual toma todos los estudiantes de mi db y me los retorna como un array funciona perfectamente en mi localhost, pero cuando lo hago con la web subida al servidor pasa lo siguiente. Obtengo los datos correctamente de la db pero al enviarlos luego de hacer el for no funciona (llega al cliente algo vacío, y no es por que los datos no estén allí ya que si ejecuto la linea comentada en lugar del for me envía el primer resultado). probé hacerlo con while, probé incluso usar query para obtener los datos pero sucede lo mismo. Me tiene desconcertado agradezco alguna ayuda.

```
   <?php
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
        header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
        
            include "conectar.php";
            $mysqli = conectarDB();
            $mysqli->set_charset('utf-8');  
        
            $students = array();
        
          if ($nueva_consulta = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 
          * FROM `estudiantes` ORDER BY `nombre`")) {
                
                $nueva_consulta->execute();
                $resultado = $nueva_consulta->get_result();
        
                if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
                
                      $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
                  
             for($i=0; $i<$resultCheck;$i++){
                 $students[$i] = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
             }
        
                   // $students = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
                    
                        echo json_encode(array('datos'=>$students, 'cantidad'=>$resultCheck  ) );                                               
                }
                else {
                      echo json_encode(array('error' => 'No hay datos'));
                }
                $nueva_consulta->close();
              }
              else{
                echo json_encode(array('error' => 'No se pudo conectar a BD'));
              }
        
        $mysqli->close();
        ?>
```

**Actualización:**
En la db tengo pocos registros para probar, de hecho solo tenia 12 estudiantes. Creo que lo he logrado solucionar (por lo menos por ahora) cuando pase los datos al servidor exporte mi base de datos con su contenido (12 estudiantes) y lo importe en el servidor. Ahora se me dio pro probar el siguiente codigo en mi archivo php:

```
 for($i=0; $i<$resultCheck;$i++)
{
     $row = json_encode($resultado->fetch_assoc());
     $students[$i] = $row;
}
```

y viendo la devolución de json_encode vi que varias filas fetch_assoc me retornaba false. Borre esos registros los cuales había precargado con la importación y así el código que tenia en un principio funciono a la perfección. No estoy seguro que provoco que en esas filas se retornara ese valor.

Comment: ¿No obtienes ningún error? ¿Has mirado el log de errores? Es posible que en el servidor no esté instalada la extensión JSON para PHP, de forma que no puedes usar la función json_encode(). Si haces un phpinfo() deberías ver un apartado json, y json support enabled.

Comment: No no me tira ningún error, y me fije en el info.php y si esta soportado (json suport: enabled)

Comment: No te tira ningún error, pero insisto ¿has mirado el log de errores? Si tienes muchísimos registros en la tabla estudiantes, es posible que PHP esté agotando el límite de memoria. Eso quedaría registrado en el log de errores.

Comment: Encontré una aparente solución al problema, allí lo coloque en la publicación como actualización. Agradezco tu ayuda.

Comment: Entonces esta solucionado y no sabemos porque? cerramos la pregunta como no reproducible???

Comment: Comento la solución definitiva: El problema era los acentos o letras como la ñ, algunos nombres que exporte en la db tenían estos caracteres, utilice  mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8"). De forma local no tengo ese problema pero bueno así ha quedado solucionado.